# Git server warn when pushing merge commits

Tags: git, merge, workflow

We have a git workflow which is mostly based on rebasing local topic branches, as to achieve as linear a commit tree as possible. However sometimes it is necessary to merge and we do allow that.

**How can I set up my git server to warn the user, when they try to push a merge commit to the server?** I would like to just warn the user and ask them to confirm that this is what they really want to do.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this interactively in the way that your question suggests if you are using standard versions of git.  One possible alternative, however, is to have a `pre-receive` hook on the server that will refuse any merge commits that don't contain a particular string, say `Merge Reviewed`.  The error output by the `pre-receive` hook on receiving a push that would introduce such a merge commit would also suggest using history rewriting (`git commit --amend` or `git rebase`) to add that string or rebase into linear history before pushing.

Comment: Reading a bit up on git hooks it seems the `update` hook should actually be perfect, as it allows interactive communication with the client. (stdout is redirected to the remote git client doing the push, and vice verse for stdin.) However I was really hoping someone has made a similar script in the past I can use or modify to my needs.